# Pipewire is not recognized by MS Teams (but Pulseaudio is)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, microsoft-teams, pipewire

Recently I moved from Pulseaudio to Pipewire ([Replacing Pulseaudio with Pipewire in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339765/replacing-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-in-ubuntu-20-04/1339897))
Everything is working as expected except for Microsoft Teams desktop app (downloaded teams_1.4.00.7556_amd64.deb package from official Microsoft site): it's showing no speakers or microphones available.
If I switch back to Pulseaudio, it works correctly.

I found a similar discussion here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/838#fromHistory
but I'm not able to apply the proposed solution (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/838#note_875806)

**EDIT:**

```
uname -a 

Linux 5.11.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 7 14:22:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dpkg -l | grep pipewire
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                                     0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64                               0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  pipewire:amd64                                              0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
rc  pipewire-audio-client-libraries:amd64                       0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - audio client libraries
ii  pipewire-bin                                                0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-locales                                            0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 all          locales for the PipeWire multimedia server - localization
ii  pipewire-media-session                                      0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        PipeWire multimedia session manager
ii  pipewire-pulse                                              0.3.29-2~ubuntu21.04                                                 amd64        PipeWire PulseAudio daemon
```

If I add the indicated "blob to the alsa-monitor.conf file", nothing changes.

Teams works in Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77-1 as a WebApp.

Comment: I suggest you add many pieces of diagnostic information, much in the same way as posted in the linked thread, plus (you probably will see if anything else *might* help):
1) `uname -a`, 
2) `dpkg -l | grep pipewire`.
Besides, 
1) What prevents you from adding the indicated "blob to the alsa-monitor.conf file"?
2) Does Teams work via bowser/s? (which, and what version/s).
Useful: https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire, https://uwot.eu/blog/microsoft-teams-on-fedora-and-wayland-with-screenshare/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with the last update (1.4.00.13653)