# Unable to use bluetooth headset, but "connecting" works. Yet, no Audio Profile

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

I have a Sony WH-CH700N Bluetooth Headset. On my previous Ubuntu it worked perfectly fine.
Now I'm using a different notebook with Kubuntu on in and I can't use it.

It's detected immediately. Strangely I am not able to select an Audio Profile. Also, I can't do anything meaningful in "Setup" (it just says it's configured successfully).

[image: Found and "connected"]

It also can obtain the information from the device:
[image: Information of Device]

The headset usually gives an audio Feedback saying "Bluetooth Connected", but that's not happening.

I started to go through the tutorial on how to use pipwire (https://askubuntu.com/a/1339897/363916)

I have installed pipewire successfully. In some tutorials it was required to restart pulse and nothing happened. Restarting pipewire interrupts the playing sound and give a visual feedback. Also:

```
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1767016071/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 33
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 79
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: qohelet
Host Name: hpbook-linux
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.40)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source
Cookie: 79ad:c27f
```

Weirdly there are no proper Profiles either:
[image: pavucontrol]

When I try to connect the headset it looks a little wrong:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Dec  1 10:18:22 hpbook-linux sssd_pac[12411]: Starting up
Dec  1 10:18:22 hpbook-linux krb5_child[12407]: Preauthentication failed
Dec  1 10:18:22 hpbook-linux krb5_child[12407]: message repeated 2 times: [ Preauthentication failed]
Dec  1 10:18:28 hpbook-linux kernel: [ 4248.095541] audit: type=1400 audit(1638350308.723:889): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/run/systemd/users/1767016071" pid=12418 comm="krb5_child" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Dec  1 10:18:29 hpbook-linux wpa_supplicant[1007]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=144400
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 2 times: [ kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2]
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 4 times: [ kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2]
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 2 times: [ kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2]
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: QDBusSignature: invalid signature ""
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Cannot get action 2 1 3 which is out of bounds
Dec  1 10:18:33 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Cannot get action 2 1 2 which is out of bounds
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12370]: blueman-manager 10.18.35 WARNING  DeviceList:193 monitor_power_levels: Failed to get power levels, probably a LE device.
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 6 times: [ kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 1 in subscription 2]
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Creating new section 5 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Creating new section 6 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 6 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 2 times: [ kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 6 in subscription 2]
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Updating existing section 0 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: kde.dbusmenuproxy: Creating new section 7 in subscription 2
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: QDBusSignature: invalid signature ""
Dec  1 10:18:35 hpbook-linux /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2419]: message repeated 9 times: [ QDBusSignature: invalid signature ""]
Dec  1 10:18:39 hpbook-linux wpa_supplicant[1007]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
```

But despite being "connected" it would turn off by itself after a while.

What I don't understand is that several guides advice the installation of ofono, while pipewire seems to not like ofono.

I am aware this is (unfortunately) quite common issue under Linux. But I did some further research and wonder what happened to bluez-firmware in 20.04?

```
$ sudo apt-get install bluez-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bluez-firmware
```

Edit(1):
The reason why I want to install it is because I assume there's something going wrong with my bluetooth:

```
 lsusb | grep Bluetooth
```

doesn't return anything.

On the other hand the service is running:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-12-01 10:45:55 CET; 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1113 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18834)
     Memory: 2.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1113 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Dez 01 10:46:09 innb02781-linux bluetoothd[1113]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
```

Edit (2):
It is probably also relevant which WiFi Chip I have:
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless-AC 9462
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
logical name: wlp0s20f3
version: 00
serial: 84:5c:f3:8e:45:13
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.10.0-1051-oem firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=10.0.0.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:16 memory:e0110000-e0113fff

So I went to https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html and downloaded the `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz` and moved the files to `/lib/firmware`.

Also no blocking:

```
$ sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

I have also tried already to turn off the wifi and connect. No difference.

After trying a lot at some point I was not even able to pair it any more. But thanks to (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293967/115043) I could do it again. Yet, there is still no audio connection.

On pairing in the command line with bluetoothctl I get this information:

```
$ bluetoothctl                            
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# trust 94:DB:56:AA:85:89
Changing 94:DB:56:AA:85:89 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 94:DB:56:AA:85:89
Attempting to pair with 94:DB:56:AA:85:89
[CHG] Device 94:DB:56:AA:85:89 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 94:DB:56:AA:85:89 Name: LE_WH-CH700N
[CHG] Device 94:DB:56:AA:85:89 Alias: LE_WH-CH700N
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0001
        00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0001/char0002
        00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0xf6d4)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0001/char0002/desc0004
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a
        69a7f243-e52f-4443-a7f9-cb4d053c74d6
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char000b
        be8692b1-3b29-410d-94d3-50281940553e
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char000d
        3f92019d-ac1d-48dc-9d94-86a0fb507591
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x5e44)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char000d/desc000f
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char0010
        5bc06a57-f84d-4086-a65a-2a238cb39cdb
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x64b4)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char0010/desc0012
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service000a/char0013
        99c3f043-8431-40e9-9802-850114e4c0d1
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015
        fe59bfa8-7fe3-4a05-9d94-99fadc69faff
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char0016
        104c022e-48d6-4dd2-8737-f8ac5489c5d4
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char0018
        69745240-ec29-4899-a2a8-cf78fd214303
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x73b4)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char0018/desc001a
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4a8d)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char001b
        70efdf00-4375-4a9e-912d-63522566d947
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x82b4)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char001b/desc001d
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char001e
        eea2e8a0-89f0-4985-a1e2-d91dc4a52632
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0015/char0020
        a79e2bd1-d6e4-4d1e-8b4f-141d69011cbb
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022
        91c10d9c-aaef-42bd-b6d6-8a648c19213d
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0023
        99d1064e-4517-46aa-8fb4-6be64dd1a1f1
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x9994)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0023/desc0025
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0026
        fbe87f6c-3f1a-44b6-b577-0bac731f6e85
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x9fd4)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0026/desc0028
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0029
        420791c0-bff5-4bd1-b957-371614031136
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0xa614)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char0029/desc002b
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char002c
        e4ef5a46-30f9-4287-a3e7-643066acb768
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0xac54)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service0022/char002c/desc002e
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service002f
        0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Amazon.com Services, Inc.
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service002f/char0030
        f04eb177-3005-43a7-ac61-a390ddf83076
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x4461)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service002f/char0032
        2beea05b-1879-4bb4-8a2f-72641f82420b
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0xc724)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_DB_56_AA_85_89/service002f/char0032/desc0034
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
```

Edit (3):
I uploaded my system information on Alsa:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=bef1ab7988c496cd50cce59779ad3135a5fa0079

Edit (4):
I have tried it with bluetooth dongles instead of the internal bluetooth. No success either. This makes me believe it's a software-related error.
I have installed the newest bluez-version from the sources. I'm not able to compile blueman, so I used the one from apt.