# Ubuntu distorts sounds at higher volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

I recently (~2 weeks) switched to Ubuntu and the sound is crazy distorted at volumes higher than 50%. At 50%, the speaker volume is not high enough for regular usage. I've so far tried tweaking around with AlsaMixer and replacing [PulseAudio with Pipewire](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339765/replacing-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-in-ubuntu-20-04) and neither solved my problem.

How do i fix this?

To see a sample of the distortion, [here's a 45 second vide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOSyj.jpg)o. You can skip ahead to 35 (-10) seconds / 15 (-30) seconds to hear the distortion.

Note - this isn't an issue with the speakers/hardware as they worked perfectly fine when I used Windows.

I own an Acer Swift 3 (2018 version) - [SF314-52](https://www.flipkart.com/order_details?order_id=OD113016101325488000&item_id=11301610132548801&unit_id=11301610132548801000). Terminal Output of `sudo lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
    Memory at b1120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Updating: adding output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC255 Analog [ALC255 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a great deal of actionable information here. Audio clarity is incredibly subjective, as a lot of people seem to think that listening to music from the speaker on their phone is “perfectly fine”. Based on your question, I’m going to assume that you know the difference between `.flac` and `.mp3`. With this in mind, could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer (or motherboard if it’s a custom-build), and the Terminal output of `sudo lspci -v` for the audio device? With this, a solution or more specific questions may be presented 

Comment: Thanks, I've added device information and terminal output.

Comment: Hmm ... it may be necessary to explicitly name the driver to use in your `alsa-base.conf` file. Could you [edit] your question (again) to include the output of `aplay -l`? This will show which specific drivers are currently assigned.

Comment: I've added this information too. Is HDA Intel PCH the driver?