# Bluetooth headphones randomly reconnect with worse sound quality

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, 21.10

I've tried a few different headsets, so the problem seems to be for sure with Ubuntu. It plays fine for a while but then randomly disconnects. Sometimes it does reconnect by itself. However, on a re-connection it is playing way worse sound quality which makes me need to turn off Bluetooth and re-enable it again. What is going on?!

edit: it disconnects a lot too

Comment: Might be related to [some issues between A2DP/HFP not working well with PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset#A2DP_not_working_with_PulseAudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one answer to this is that the headset might switch its connection profile. If your audio system doesn't open the microphone, then newer Bluetooth headsets probably will choose A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile) as audio connection. This greatly improves the audio quality but negates the option to use the Bluetooth connection for the microphone at the same time.

If you open the microphone channel it has to drop back to a telephone quality headset mode. This might cause a short disconnection in the audio transmission.

If I don't listen to music but have to attend meetings where I need the microphone from time to time, I always have an application like the control panel or mumble running in background to ensure, the mic line remains open.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339765/replacing-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-in-ubuntu-20-04) e.g. switch to [pipewire](https://pipewire.org/)

...more info on how to do this on 21.10 see [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/enable-pipewire-audio-service-ubuntu-21-04/)