# Bluetooth headset codecs in Ubuntu 18.04 vs 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, codecs, headset, pipewire

I know that Ubuntu (PulseAudio) has well-known issues with Bluetooth Headsets and for some time I was struggling to fix this.
After different attempts [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339765/replacing-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-in-ubuntu-20-04) helped me and everything seems to be working. I even managed to make auto-switch profiles work when I use a microphone.

But I use two Ubuntu systems (18.04 and 20.04) and available codecs differ for the same headphones on both systems. Even though I checked all the configs, installed packages, logs, etc., everything looks exactly the same.

On 20.04 I have **AAC** codec **by default** and **mSBC** when using a **microphone** which is nice.
But on 18.04 I have **SBC** codec **by default** and **CVSD** when using a **microphone** which is worse.

All available profiles on 18.04:

- Headset Head Unit (HSP/HPF, codec CVSD)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC)

All available profiles on 20.04:

- Headset Head Unit (HSP/HPF, codec mSBC)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec AAC)

How to bring the same codecs to 18.04 to make the quality better?

**/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/bluez-monitor.conf** (the same for both systems, pretty much default but **bluez5.autoswitch-profile** set to true):

```
# Bluez monitor config file for PipeWire version 0.4.1 #
#
# Copy and edit this file in /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/
# for system-wide changes or in
# ~/.config/pipewire/media-session.d/ for local changes.

properties = {
    # These features do not work on all headsets, so they are enabled
    # by default based on the hardware database. They can also be
    # forced on/off for all devices by the following options:

    #bluez5.enable-sbc-xq    = true
    #bluez5.enable-msbc      = true
    #bluez5.enable-hw-volume = true
    #bluez5.enable-faststream = true

    # See bluez-hardware.conf for the hardware database.

    # Enabled headset roles (default: [ hsp_hs hfp_ag ]), this
    # property only applies to native backend. Currently some headsets
    # (Sony WH-1000XM3) are not working with both hsp_ag and hfp_ag
    # enabled, disable either hsp_ag or hfp_ag to work around it.
    #
    # Supported headset roles: hsp_hs (HSP Headset),
    #                          hsp_ag (HSP Audio Gateway),
    #                          hfp_hf (HFP Hands-Free),
    #                          hfp_ag (HFP Audio Gateway)
    #bluez5.headset-roles = [ hsp_hs hsp_ag hfp_hf hfp_ag ]

    # Enabled A2DP codecs (default: all).
    #bluez5.codecs = [ sbc sbc_xq aac ldac aptx aptx_hd aptx_ll aptx_ll_duplex faststream faststream_duplex ]

    # HFP/HSP backend (default: native).
    # Available values: any, none, hsphfpd, ofono, native
    #bluez5.hfphsp-backend = native

    # Properties for the A2DP codec configuration
    #bluez5.default.rate     = 48000
    #bluez5.default.channels = 2

    # Register dummy AVRCP player, required for AVRCP volume function.
    # Disable if you are running mpris-proxy or equivalent.
    #bluez5.dummy-avrcp-player = true
}

rules = [
    # An array of matches/actions to evaluate.
    {
        # Rules for matching a device or node. It is an array of
        # properties that all need to match the regexp. If any of the
        # matches work, the actions are executed for the object.
        matches = [
            {
                # This matches all cards.
                device.name = "~bluez_card.*"
            }
        ]
        actions = {
            # Actions can update properties on the matched object.
            update-props = {

                # Auto-connect device profiles on start up or when only partial
                # profiles have connected. Disabled by default if the property
                # is not specified.
                #bluez5.auto-connect = [
                #    hfp_hf
                #    hsp_hs
                #    a2dp_sink
                #    hfp_ag
                #    hsp_ag
                #    a2dp_source
                #]
                bluez5.auto-connect = [ hfp_hf hsp_hs a2dp_sink ]

                # Hardware volume control (default: all)
                #bluez5.hw-volume = [
                #    hfp_hf
                #    hsp_hs
                #    a2dp_sink
                #    hfp_ag
                #    hsp_ag
                #    a2dp_source
                #]

                # LDAC encoding quality
                # Available values: auto (Adaptive Bitrate, default)
                #                   hq   (High Quality, 990/909kbps)
                #                   sq   (Standard Quality, 660/606kbps)
                #                   mq   (Mobile use Quality, 330/303kbps)
                #bluez5.a2dp.ldac.quality = auto

                # AAC variable bitrate mode
                # Available values: 0 (cbr, default), 1-5 (quality level)
                #bluez5.a2dp.aac.bitratemode = 0

                # Profile connected first
                # Available values: a2dp-sink (default), headset-head-unit
                #bluez5.profile = a2dp-sink

                # A2DP <-> HFP profile auto-switching (when device is default output)
                # Available values: false, role (default), true
                # 'role' will switch the profile if the recording application
                # specifies Communication (or "phone" in PA) as the stream role.
                bluez5.autoswitch-profile = true
            }
        }
    }
    {
        matches = [
            {
                # Matches all sources.
                node.name = "~bluez_input.*"
            }
            {
                # Matches all sinks.
                node.name = "~bluez_output.*"
            }
        ]
        actions = {
            update-props = {
                #node.nick                       = "My Node"
                #node.nick                       = null
                #priority.driver                 = 100
                #priority.session                = 100
                node.pause-on-idle               = false
                #resample.quality                = 4
                #channelmix.normalize            = false
                #channelmix.mix-lfe              = false
                #session.suspend-timeout-seconds = 5            # 0 disables suspend
                #monitor.channel-volumes         = false

                # A2DP source role, "input" or "playback"
                # Defaults to "playback", playing stream to speakers
                # Set to "input" to use as an input for apps
                #bluez5.a2dp-source-role = input
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**upd.** Looks like the reason is bluez version. Ubuntu 20.04 has bluez5.53 while Ubuntu 18.04 latest version is bluez5.48.
I tried looking for PPAs, found only one (ppa:bluetooth/bluez) which offers 5.50 version. But unfortunately, it changes nothing.
Any good way to upgrade bluez version in Ubuntu 18.04 to the latest one? Only manual compiling?