# no sound, pulseaudio seems broken, dameon startup failed

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

can't find any solution to this problem in the other posts.
I have no more sound on Ubuntu.
I removed and reinstalled pulseaudio but I still have this:

```
$ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

and

```
$ sudo pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory 
(/home/louisro/.config/pulse): Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied


$ ps -ef | grep pulse
louisro   8703  3418  0 21:45 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse
$ pacmd list-cards
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
louisro@-ThinkPad-T400:~/.config$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

Also reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio gives this and wrecks my system parameters and I have to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to restore them:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-timer.
```

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: `systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket` please. And `pactl info | grep -i server`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing PiperWire instead of PulseAudio since it has low latency and its more flexible. for more information : https://lwn.net/Articles/847412/

Assuming you are on Ubuntu 22.04 @1nfern0 has discussed the proper way to install PipeWire at:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1339897/1638745